# How can I get highstock zoom infomation?

Tags: highcharts

I want do something when I change the zoom if highstock. 
I can listen the redraw event then I kown its changed, but how can i get the zoom infomation?

Answer (score 1):

You can catch setExtremes() event http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.setExtremes and afterSetExtremes http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes